# Property 'x' is missing in Type 'y'

Tags: typescript, interface

This code compiled before TypeScript 1.8 and now not anymore.

```
//[in app3.ts]
declare module App {

    export interface Iaa {
        nb: number;
    }

    export interface Ibb extends Iaa {
        title: string;
    }

}
```

and

```
//[in app4.ts:]
/// <reference path="app3.ts"/>

module App {
"use strict";

export interface Iaa extends aa {
}

export class aa {

    constructor() {
    }

    test(): void {
        var that: Iaa = <Iaa>this; //Error
    }
}

export interface Ibb extends bb{
}

export class bb extends aa {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    test(): void {
        var that: Ibb = <Ibb>this;//Error
        that.nb = 10;
    }

}
}
```

Here's the error:
app4.ts(15,29): error TS2352: Neither type 'this' nor type 'Iaa' is assignable to the other.
  Type 'aa' is not assignable to type 'Iaa'.
    Property 'nb' is missing in type 'aa'.

Can someone explain me why 'nb' and 'title' are undefined when they are in app3.ts ?
thank you

Comment: why interface extends class?

Comment: From the official Doc : "When an interface type extends a class type it inherits the members of the class but not their implementations"

Comment: So the error pretty much explaining itself - there's no property `nb` in `aa`

Comment: My question is Why this code compiled before 1.8.

Comment: looks like it was a bug

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question :

> Can someone explain me why 'nb' and 'title' are undefined when they are in app3.ts ?

It's may be because you try to put in an `Iaa` one instance of `aa`, which have nothing in common with `Iaa`(no property matching).To be able to do that `aa` need to implement `Iaa` or at least have the same property.
Same for the case `Ibb`

There is how to make your code work again.

```js
declare module App {

    export interface Iaa {
        nb: number;
    }

    export interface Ibb extends Iaa {
        title: string;
    }

}

module App {
    "use strict";

    export interface Iaa extends aa {
    }

    export class aa {

        constructor() {
        }

        test(): void {
            var that: Iaa = <Iaa>this; //Error
        }

        nb: number; // <-- add that
    }

    export interface Ibb extends bb {
    }

    export class bb extends aa {

        constructor() {
            super();
        }

        test(): void {
            var that: Ibb = this as Ibb;//Error
            that.nb = 10;
        }

        title: string; // <-- add that
    }
```